# Ruby convert array to nested hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
value = 42  
array = ["this","is","a","test"]
```

how can I convert that to get this

```
{ "this" => { "is" => { "a" => { "test" => 42 } } } }
```

the array is always flat.

Thank you!

Comment: Now that's an insane data structure... would it happen to have any justification?

Comment: @delnan "hi.i.am.some.kind.of.path=value" to be merged in an existing yaml hash dump.

Comment: @delnan Another example would be to eager load a bunch of chained tables specified by an "array" like `join1:join2:join3:column1`. So I would need to `eager_load(join1: {join2: :join3})`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
array.reverse.inject(value) { |assigned_value, key| { key => assigned_value } }
#=> {"this"=>{"is"=>{"a"=>{"test"=>42}}}}
```

Comment: The most difficult part of this was figuring out how to phrase my question on SO. "Nested" was the turning point ;)

Comment: You have achieved what I have been trying to achieve in about 50 lines less than my best attempt LOL.

Comment: Somebody needs to explain how this magic works. Been trying to do this unsuccessfully for 60 minutes.

Comment: Okay, I'll explain for myself and others. Firstly, this is clever in its simplicity. Using `reverse` and `inject` it first creates a Hash with the last `key` ("test") and the final value (42). It then takes that Hash and assigns it to the second last `key` ("a") and keeps going until it reaches the first `key` in the original Array. The result is a perfectly nested Hash. Nice one!