# Access nested hash element specified by an array of keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to get a general solution to the problem of accessing an element in a nested hash given an array of key values,e.g.:

```
hash = { "a" => { "b" => 'foo' }}
array = ["a", "b"]

function(array)
=> "foo"
```

I'm guessing this could be a one-liner. It also is quite closely related to this problem:
[Ruby convert array to nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095077/ruby-convert-array-to-nested-hash)

Comment: I did not spot that - whoops

Comment: The link you have given.. is awesome..I learnt a new concept from that..thanks for finding it out... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
hash = { "a" => { "b" => 'foo' }}
array = ["a", "b"]

array.inject(hash,:fetch)
# => "foo"
array.inject(hash,:[])
# => "foo"
```

Comment: Thanks! In case it helps anyone else, I came across this answer while looking for a Ruby equivalent to Clojure's `get-in`.