# Ruby - Set Value of nested hash from array of keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I learned from [Access nested hash element specified by an array of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251454/access-nested-hash-element-specified-by-an-array-of-keys))

that if i have a array

```
array = ['person', 'age']
```

and I have a nested hash

```
hash = {:person => {:age => 30, :name => 'tom'}}
```

I can get the value of of age by using

```
array.inject(hash, :fetch)
```

But How would I then **set** the value of :age to 40 with the array of keys?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the hash that contains the last key in the array (by removing the last element), then set the key's value:

```
array.map!(&:to_sym) # make sure keys are symbols

key = array.pop
array.inject(hash, :fetch)[key] = 40

hash # => {:person=>{:age=>40, :name=>"tom"}}
```

If you don't want to modify the array you can use `.last` and `[0...-1]`:

```
keys = array.map(&:to_sym)

key = keys.last
keys[0...-1].inject(hash, :fetch)[key] = 40
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, I overlooked that. I also added an alternate solution if it's important to preserve the array.

Comment: Still not testing! If you don't want to modify `array`, `keys = array.map(&:to_sym); key = keys.last...`. (Ah, yes, it's `pop`. I had `shift` on the brain.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion:

```
def set_hash_value(h, array, value)
  curr_key = array.first.to_sym
  case array.size
  when 1 then h[curr_key] = value
  else set_hash_value(h[curr_key], array[1..-1], value)
  end
  h
end

set_hash_value(hash, array, 40)
  #=> {:person=>{:age=>40, :name=>"tom"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the [set](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash#rodashset-example) method from the [rodash](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash) gem in order to set a deeply nested value into a hash.

```rb
require 'rodash'

hash = { person: { age: 30, name: 'tom' } }

key = [:person, :age]
value = 40

Rodash.set(hash, key, value)

hash
# => {:person=>{:age=>40, :name=>"tom"}}
```